# Сравнение двух столбцов, при совпадении копировать в другой столбец

Tags: excel, сравнение, excel-формулы

Как выполнить сравнение двух столбцов A и H на повторяющиеся значения, и в случае совпадения значений, копировать содержимое B, C, D, E в соответствующую строку столбца I, J, K. столбцы B и I сравнивать не надо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте функцию ВПР()